# Looking for a specific passage by Nabokov

Tags: identification-request, russian-language, vladimir-nabokov

I remember reading this specific (germanophobic, sorry about that) bit in one of Nabokov's works but I just can't find it now. It described several bürgers drinking beer and casually laughing at someone's death.

At first I was pretty certain it was from "The Gift" but I'm not too sure about that anymore, since searching the full text didn't help. Can anyone, by any chance, help me find a precise quote (either in Russian or in English)?

Comment: Any other details you can remember? I skimmed through the Russian version of _The Gift_, but found nothing. Do any other keywords come to your mind?

Comment: I replaced `quote-identification` with `story-identification`, in accordance with their respective usage guidelines.

Comment: @Gallifreyan The problem is that I don't really remember any keywords. I just remember that, with his usual subtlety, he did not accentuate​ that such behaviour was (what he perceived as) a trait of the German national character. That was, however, clear from the context. I'm also pretty sure he used some interjection similar to "ha-ha" to imitate the laughter.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I knew there had to be something more fitting!

Comment: Are you positive that it was a novel, and not a short story?  That would narrow it down quite a bit.  Also, was the death that of a character in the story, or were they laughing at a news report or something like that?

Comment: @KevinTroy No, I probably didn't make that clear enough, but by now I'm not sure at all where it was from. I am positive it was Nabokov though =) The death was of just some person, not a character.

Comment: Death, laugher and Germans. Would have been narrowing down the scope quite a lot for anyone but Nabokov ...

Answer (score 7):

Here is a passage from *The Gift* which depicts two Germans as brutish and indifferent to human suffering.

> Yasha's death had its most painful effect on his father.... Meanwhile nothing stopped with Yasha's death and many interesting things were happening: in Russia one observed the spread of abortions and the revival of summer houses; in England there were strikes of some kind or other.... and one Sunday **a young Berlin merchant with his locksmith friend** set out on a trip to the country in a large, four-wheel cart with only the slightest smell of blood, rented from his neighbor, a butcher: two fat servant maids and the merchant's two small children sat in plush chairs set on the wagon, the children cried, **the merchant and his pal guzzled beer** and drove the horses hard, the weather was beautiful so that, **in their high spirits, they deliberately hit a cleverly cornered cyclist, beat him up violently** in the ditch, tore his port-folio to bits (he was an artist) **and rolled on, very happy**, and when he had come to his senses, the artist overtook them in a tavern garden, but the policeman who tried to establish their identities was also beaten up, after which they **very happily** rolled on along the highway, and when they saw that police motorcycles were gaining on them, **they opened fire with revolvers and in the ensuing gunplay a bullet killed the merry merchant's three-year-old son.**
>
> (*The Gift*, pp. 49-50)

The passage does not explicitly mention laughter, but it does portray the Germans as "very happy" in the face of their brutish acts. We are led to believe that they will be indifferent to the fact that their actions have led to the death of the three-year-old.

There are many other places where Nabokov depicts Germans, in both positive and negative light. They frequently make appearances in the stories he wrote while living in Berlin. For example, the story "Cloud, Castle, Lake" is about a Russian emigre who is bullied by Germans on a mandatory vacation, and "The Fight" is about a quarrel between Germans in a tavern.

Comment: I too found that passage but disregarded it. I'll try to dig up the Russian version by tomorrow.

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the quote by Silenus, I can remember two more germanophobic passages. The first one is about Fyodor's student (and it mentions humor):

> Он был самодоволен, рассудителен, туп и по-немецки невежественен, т.е. относился ко всему, чего не знал, скептически. Твердо считая, что смешная сторона вещей давным-давно разработана там, где ей и полагается быть – на последней странице берлинского иллюстрированного еженедельника, – он никогда не смеялся – разве только снисходительно хмыкал. Единственное, что еще мало-мальски могло его развеселить, это рассказ о какой-нибудь остроумной денежной операции. Вся философия жизни сократилась у него до простейшего положения: бедный несчастлив, богатый счастлив. Это узаконенное счастье игриво складывалось, под аккомпанемент первоклассной танцевальной музыки, из различных предметов технической роскоши. На урок он норовил прийти всегда на несколько минут раньше и старался уйти на столько же позже.
>
> *(Владимир Набоков, Дар)*

Translated:

> He was self-satisfied, discursive, obtuse and **germanically ignorant**; i.e., he treated everything he did not know with skepticism. **Firmly believing that the humorous side of things had long since been worked out in the proper place for it (the back page of a Berlin illustrated weekly), he never laughed, or limited himself to a condescending snicker. The only thing that could just barely amuse him was a story about some ingenious
>   financial operation.** His whole philosophy of life had been reduced to the simplest proposition: the poor man is unhappy, the rich man is happy. This legalized happiness was playfully put together to the accompaniment of first-class dance music, out of various items of technical luxury. For the lesson he always did his best to come a little before the hour and tried to leave a little after it.
>
> *(The Gift by Vladimir Nabokov, translated by Michael Scammell with the collaboration of the author)*

And the second, the most germanophobic in the whole novel in my opinion:

> Он ехал на урок, как всегда опаздывал, и, как всегда, в нем росла смутная, скверная, тяжелая ненависть и к неуклюжей медлительности этого бездарнейшего из всех способов передвижения, и к безнадежно-знакомым, безнадежно-некрасивым улицам, шедшим за мокрым окном, а главное – к ногам, бокам, затылкам туземных пассажиров. Он рассудком знал, что среди них могут быть и настоящие, вполне человеческие особи, с бескорыстными страстями, чистыми печалями, даже с воспоминаниями, просвечивающими сквозь жизнь, – но почему-то ему сдавалось, что все эти скользящие, холодные зрачки, посматривающие на него так, словно он провозил незаконное сокровище (как в сущности оно и было), принадлежат лишь гнусным кумушкам и гнилым торгашам. Русское убеждение, что в малом количестве немец пошл, а в большом – пошл нестерпимо, было, он знал это, убеждением, недостойным художника; а все-таки его пробирала дрожь, – и только угрюмый кондуктор с загнанными глазами и пластырем на пальце, вечно-мучительно ищущий равновесия и прохода среди судорожных толчков вагона и скотской тесноты стоящих, внешне казался, если не человеком, то хоть бедным родственником человека. На второй остановке перед Федором Константиновичем сел сухощавый, в полупальто с лисьим воротником, в зеленой шляпе и потрепанных гетрах, мужчина, – севши, толкнул его коленом да углом толстого, с кожаной хваткой, портфеля – и тем самым обратил его раздражение в какое-то ясное бешенство, так что, взглянув пристально на сидящего, читая его черты, он мгновенно сосредоточил на нем всю свою грешную ненависть (к жалкой, бедной, вымирающей нации) и отчетливо знал, за что ненавидит его: за этот низкий лоб, за эти бледные глаза; за фольмильх и экстраштарк, – подразумевающие законное существование разбавленного и поддельного; за полишинелевый строй движений, – угрозу пальцем детям – не как у нас стойком стоящее напоминание о небесном Суде, а символ колеблющейся палки, – палец, а не перст; за любовь к частоколу, ряду, заурядности; за культ конторы; за то, что если прислушаться, что у него говорится внутри (или к любому разговору на улице), неизбежно услышишь цифры, деньги; за дубовый юмор и пипифаксовый смех; за толщину задов у обоего пола, – даже если в остальной своей части субъект и не толст; за отсутствие брезгливости; за видимость чистоты – блеск кастрюльных днищ на кухне и варварскую грязь ванных комнат; за склонность к мелким гадостям, за аккуратность в гадостях, за мерзкий предмет, аккуратно нацепленный на решетку сквера; за чужую живую кошку, насквозь проткнутую в отместку соседу проволокой, к тому же ловко закрученной с конца; за жестокость во всем, самодовольную, как-же-иначную; за неожиданную восторженную услужливость, с которой человек пять прохожих помогают тебе подбирать оброненные гроши; за… Так он нанизывал пункты пристрастного обвинения, глядя на сидящего против него, – покуда тот не вынул из кармана номер васильевской «Газеты», равнодушно кашлянув с русской интонацией.
>
> *(Владимир Набоков, Дар)*

Translated:

> He was going to a lesson, was late as usual, and as usual **there grew in him a vague, evil, heavy hatred** for the clumsy sluggishness of this least gifted of all methods of transport, for the hopelessly familiar, hopelessly ugly streets going by the wet window, and **most of all for the feet, sides and necks of the native passengers. His reason knew that they could also include genuine, completely human individuals with unselfish passions, pure sorrows, even with memories shining through life, but for some reason he got the impression that all these cold, slippery eyes, looking at him as if he were carrying an illegal treasure (which his gift was, essentially), belonged only to malicious hags and crooked hucksters. The Russian conviction that the German is in small numbers vulgar and in large numbers—unbearably vulgar was, he knew, a conviction unworthy of an artist; but nonetheless he was seized with a trembling, and only the gloomy conductor with hunted eyes and a plaster on his finger, eternally and painfully seeking equilibrium and room to pass amidst the convulsive jolts of the car and the cattle-like crowding of standing passengers, seemed outwardly, if not a human being, then at least a poor relation to a human being.** At the second stop a lean man in a short coat with a fox-fur collar, wearing a green hat and frayed spats, sat down in front of Fyodor. In settling down he bumped him with his knee and with the corner of a fat briefcase with a leather handle, and this trivial thing turned his irritation into a kind of pure fury, so that, staring fixedly at the sitter, reading his features, he instantly concentrated on him all his sinful hatred (for this poor, pitiful, expiring nation) and **knew precisely why he hated him: for that low forehead, for those pale eyes; for Vollmilch and Extra-stark, implying the lawful existence of the diluted and the artificial; for the Punchinello-like system of gestures (threatening children not as we do—with an upright finger, a standing reminder of Divine Judgment—but with a horizontal digit imitating a waving stick); for a love of fences, rows, mediocrity; for the cult of the office; for the fact that if you listen to his inner voice (or to any conversation on the street) you will inevitably hear figures, money; for the lavatory humor and crude laughter; for the fatness of the backsides of both sexes, even if the rest of the subject is not fat; for the lack of fastidiousness; for the visibility of cleanliness—the gleam of saucepan bottoms in the kitchen and the barbaric filth of the bathrooms; for the weakness for dirty little tricks, for taking pains with dirty tricks, for the abominable object stuck carefully on the railings of the public gardens; for someone else’s live cat, pierced through with wire as revenge on a neighbor, and the wire cleverly twisted at one end; for oruelty in everything, self-satisfied, taken for granted; for the unexpected, rapturous helpfulness with which five passersby help you to pick up some dropped farthings**; for.... Thus he threaded the points of his biased indictment, looking at the man who sat opposite him—until the latter took a copy of Vasiliev’s newspaper from his pocket and coughed unconcernedly with a Russian intonation.
>
> *(The Gift by Vladimir Nabokov, translated by Michael Scammell with the collaboration of the author)*

Ironically, both these passages, while critical of Germans, describe Russians (Fyodor's student and a man on a tram).

Answer (score 0):

I have vague memories of such scenes (always with Germans, beer, and laughter; death is a flexible point) in several books of Nabokov -- *Защита Лужина*, *Смех в темноте*/*Laughter in the Dark*, and possibly *The Real Life of Sebastian Knight*.

One I was able to find quickly is this, from Отчаяние, chapter 5:

> “Ничего о таких вещах я не слыхал, и не знаю, — довольно гру- бо
>   возразил Феликс. — У тетки моей был сын, который паясничал на
>   ярмарках, — вот все, что я знаю, — был он пьяница и разврат- ник, и
>   тетка моя все глаза из-за него выплакала, пока он, слава Богу, не
>   разбился на смерть, грохнувшись с качелей. Эти кинема- тографы да
>   цирки — — ” Так ли все это было? Верно-ли следую моей памяти, или же,
>   вы- бившись из строя, своевольно пляшет мое перо? Что-то уже слиш- ком
>   литературен этот наш разговор, смахивает на застеночные бе- седы в
>   бутафорских кабаках имени Достоевского; еще немного, и появится
>   “сударь”, даже в квадрате: “сударь-с”, — знакомый взвол- нованный
>   говорок: “и уже непременно, непременно...”, а там и весь мистический
>   гарнир нашего отечественного Пинкертона. Меня да- же некоторым образом
>   мучит, то есть даже не мучит, а совсем, совсем сбивает с толку и,
>   пожалуй, губит меня мысль, что я как то слишком понадеялся на свое
>   перо... Узнаете тон этой фразы? Вот именно. И еще мне кажется, что
>   разговор-то наш помню пре- восходно, со всеми его оттенками, и всю его
>   подноготную (вот опять, — любимое словцо нашего специалиста по
>   душевным лихо- радкам и аберрациям человеческого достоинства, —
>   “подноготная” и еще, пожалуй, курсивом). Да, помню этот разговор, но
>   пере- дать его в точности не могу, что-то мешает мне, что-то жгучее,
>   нестерпимое, гнусное, — от чего я не могу отвязаться, прилипло, все
>   равно как если в потемках нарваться на мухоморную бумагу, — и,
>   главное, не знаешь, где зажигается свет. Нет, разговор наш был не
>   таков, каким он изложен, — то есть может быть слова-то и бы- ли именно
>   такие (вот опять), но не удалось мне, или не посмел я, передать особые
>   шумы, сопровождавшие его, — были какие-то провалы и удаления звука, и
>   затем снова бормотание и шушу- кание, и вдруг деревянный голос, ясно
>   выговаривающий: “Давай, Феликс, выпьем еще пивца”.

Comment: Please could you provide an English translation for this passage? (Either your own or from a published translation, whichever is easiest.)

Answer (score 0):

The keywords in your question reminded me of "Cloud, Castle, Lake" from "Nabokov's Dozen" in which a Vasiliy Ivanovich is traveling on a train with a group of Germans, all called Schramm or Schultz. He is made to sing (in German), has to hand over his provisions ("The cucumber amused everybody, was pronouced inedible, and was thrown out of the window"). They spend the night at an inn. The next day, again on a train, "There was much laughter". Beer is also mentioned.

Could this be what you were looking for?

I don't have the book with me at this moment, so I need to quote from [Google Books](https://books.google.nl/books?id=eAQhuAZzfYIC).